# Threading in Android Application

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm fairly new to Android development. When I was creating my first programs, I was just running everything on the main thread because they were very small applications. I have started using web APIs in my application and know that anything dealing with networking should have its own thread. I've tried multiple examples with AsyncTasks and using Thread and Handlers but I'm having trouble applying it to my own code, so I bring it here for thoughts and suggestions on how to thread what I currently have below.

Quick code overview: I'm receiving input from another activity and creating an HTTP request for the web API based on that input. I receive the JSON back and pull out an ID number. I then have to use the ID number to make another HTTP request to the web API where I then parse the JSON and create an array adapter to display a list in my activity.

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

imports ....


public class BREWERYMessageActivity extends ListActivity {
    //Variable from another Activity
    public final static String BREWERY_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.BREWERY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           Intent intent = getIntent();
           final String brewery = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.BREWERY_MESSAGE);


    try {
     URL breweryDBurl = new URL("web api url using brewery variable");

     URLConnection conn = breweryDBurl.openConnection();

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                conn.getInputStream()));


        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(inputLine);

            JSONArray jArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("data");


            JSONObject obj1 = (JSONObject)jArray.getJSONObject(0);

            String ID;

            try{
                 ID = obj1.getString("id");
                }catch(Exception e){
                  ID = "N/A";   
                }


            try {
               URL DBurl = new URL("Second web API call using the ID");

            URLConnection con = DBurl.openConnection();

                BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader(
                                        new InputStreamReader(
                                        con.getInputStream()));

                String inputLn;

                ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

                while ((inputLn = inpt.readLine()) != null) {

                    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(inputLn);

                    JSONArray jArry = jsonobj.getJSONArray("data");

                    String name;

                     for(int i = 0; i < jArry.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)jArry.getJSONObject(i);


                         try{
                            name = obj.getString("name");
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                name = "N/A";
                            }


                         if(!(name.equals("N/A"))) 
                            stringList.add(name);
                            }
                         name = ""; 
                     }
                }   

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BREWERYMessageActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }catch(Exception e){
                // Create the text view
                TextView textView = new TextView(BREWERYMessageActivity.this);
                textView.setTextSize(20);
                textView.setText("Not Available");
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                // Set the text view as the activity layout
                setContentView(textView);


            }




        }



    }catch(Exception e){
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(BREWERYMessageActivity.this);
        textView.setTextSize(20);
        textView.setText("Not Available");
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

}

Comment: `I'm having trouble applying it to my own code` unclear.

Comment: YOu may have more luck on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) anyway. So in doInBackground you realy can't update anything in UI like Views as Buttons, TextViews, etc...

For update UI thread if necessary use [onPreExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29), [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) and [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

E.g. place the code block since `URL breweryDBurl = new URL("web api url using brewery variable");` until `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BREWERYMessageActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList);` inside [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) method and returns the adapter to `setListAdapter(adapter);` inside [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

This article is excellent to undertand the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and all your capabilties.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thank you Marcelo, after some more fiddling around I was able to make this happen. I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marcelo's answer, you should never change your listadapter or the values with which it was created inside any other thread than the UI thread.

So it's safer to create a new list of values in the doinbackground (your stringList), and afterwards creating the ArrayAdapter and calling setlistadapter in the onPostExecute instead of already creating the arrayadapter inside the doInBackground.

Otherwise you're prone to the

> The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification.
>   Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but
>   only from the UI thread.

error. This is an error that pops up very irregularly (it only started happening to me after quite some time working like Marcelo stated, I was blissfully unaware for a full day until it started occurring from time to time)

Comment: This error could be happen because you trying update a List reference setted in an adapter. The adapter could listening when List change and try to update yourself causing thread error.

Comment: Thank you SvenT and Marcelo, I was able to figure it out with your help and comments. I greatly appreciate it!